# C++ class and CUDA error

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to write a simple C++ class with some CUDA features. I got this error and could not figure out what went wrong:

main.cu: error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Here is the code:

```
//add_values.cu
#include "add.h"

__global__ void add::add_values(int *a, int *b, int *c){

  int tid  = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  while (tid < N){
  {
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
    cout << c[i] << endl;
    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  }
}

//main.cu
#include "add.h"

#define N (33*1024)

int main(void){

  add add_test;
  int a[N], b[N], c[N];
  int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N*sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] = i*i;
    c[i] = 0;
  }

  cudaMemcpy (dev_a, a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy (dev_b, b, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


  add_test.add_values<<<128, 128>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c); //Error?

  cudaMemcpy (dev_c, c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(dev_a);
  cudaFree(dev_b);
  cudaFree(dev_c);

  return 0;

}
```

Something went wrong when I was trying to call the add_values function in main. Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot have a `__global__` function as a class member. Refactor you code.

Answer (score 1):

```
__global__ void add::add_values(int *a, int *b, int *c){ // level1
 ...
  while (tid < N){ // level2
  { // level3
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
    cout << c[i] << endl;
    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  } // end of level3
} // end of level2
```

You're not closing level 1